# Typed unsealed object does not allow new props

Tags: flowtype

Why flow does not allow new props to be written into typed [unsealed object](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-unsealed-objects):

```
type T = {
  a: string;
};

const t: T = {};
t.a = 'test'; // ok
t.b = 22; //      ^ Cannot assign `22` to `t.b` because property `b` is missing in `T` [1]. [prop-missing]
```

Changing `T` to inexact type does not help:

```
type T = {
  a: string,
  ...
}
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeAoKUCGAuKBnYATgJYB2A5gNxpQB0dKAvlSgMYD2J+UwOciSTFMBoYEUAOTAI+cRSgB6eVDYBrITQBGYgEzaKQA)

Comment: _The unsealedness of the empty object literal is masked by the fact that you are immediately annotating the value you are assigning it to_ This is explanation I've got [here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8430#issuecomment-654988260) So you were right in your original answer. I just couldn't wrap my head around it . Now it is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You have **Sealed object**. From Flow documentation:

> When you create an object with its properties, you create a sealed
> object type in Flow. These sealed objects will know all of the
> properties you declared them with and the types of their values.
>
> ...
>
> But when objects are sealed, Flow will not allow you to add new properties to them.

[Sealed objects](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-sealed-objects)

So, you need to use **Unsealed object**:

```
// @flow
var obj = {};

obj.foo = 1;       // Works!
obj.bar = true;    // Works!
obj.baz = 'three'; // Works!
```

[Unsealed objects](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-unsealed-objects)

For example, you can create object `foo` with prop `a` as string. Then create a brand new object `bar` which contains props from `foo` and new prop `b` as number:

```
// @flow

type Obj = { a: string };

const foo: Obj = { a: 'Foo' };
const bar: Obj = { ...foo, b: 10 };
```

[Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AeQEYBWoAvKAN6gCGAXKAM4oBOAlgHYDmoAvgNzIBjWG0ahIsWHQLEylWqADkAMQkKe-ISJSh8VJlKKkKoAHRnxsADQ66ARgAM6oA)

Comment: Yeah thanks! It looks like a workaround solution. But mainly question is why  unsealed object with specified type does not allow new props?

Comment: Hi Alex, your `type T = { a: string };` from question is `Sealed object`. Unsealed object allows you to add new prop right?

Comment: Hi Marko, `T` is a `type`. Unsealed object is `const t: T = {}` - so `t` is an `unsealed` object typed as `T`.

Comment: Flow doesn't look at const t: T = {} as unsealed object. Because `T ` is `Sealed object` by definition. Minimal representation of `t` is to be empty object or to have prop `a` as *string*. Adding new props to `t` with (dot notation) doesn't allowed: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-optional-object-type-properties But you can achieve that with spread operator (example inside answer).

Comment: Why [this case](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagCqgLygDeiooAhgFygDOyATgJYB2A5gNyIC+niAxrGZ1QyankIkyVUAHJkmOjIA0pUIwAm1AIwAmHdyA) is ok then? ;)